# Python keeps displaying 'module not found' error. How do I fix this?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've been trying to install the google cloud vision module for python and I have installed it.
However, python just keeps displaying the module not found error.

```
>>> import google
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'google'
```

Comment: There is not enough information in your question to help debug your issue

Comment: How did you install the module? If you run `python -m pip freeze`, do you see it installed?

Answer (score -1):

```
from google.cloud import vision
```